# ImageWMS layer doesn't work in 3D mode

Tags: openlayers, wms, cesium, ol-cesium

I would like to display an ImageWMS layer using OpenLayers v6.3.1, OL-Cesium v2.9 and Cesium v1.70 in 3D mode. In 2D mode it is perfect, however in 3D mode, I don't see the states ImageWMS layer, the map show only the OSM basemap. There are no errors on the browser's console and on the Network tab there are no WMS requests.

Any suggestions? How can I solve this issue?

This is my code below:

```
<head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/css/ol.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.70/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="Cesium.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol-cesium@2.9.0/css/olcs.css">
    <script src="olcesium.js"></script>
    <style>
        html,
        body,
        #olCesMap {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #btnSwitchMap {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 50px;
            z-index: 2;
            padding: 4px;
        }
    </style>
</head>  
<body>
    <div id="olCesMap">
        <button id="btnSwitchMap" onclick="cesViewer.setEnabled(!cesViewer.getEnabled());">Switch 2D/3D</button>
    </div>
    <script defer>
        var controls = ol.control.defaults({
            rotate: true,
            rotateOptions: {
                tipLabel: "Reset rotation. \nUse Alt+Shift+Drag to rotate the map."
            }
        });
        var interactions = ol.interaction.defaults({ altShiftDragRotate: true, pinchRotate: true });

        // Declaring Zoom level to further view
        var zoom = 5;
        // Declaring Map center
        var center = ol.proj.fromLonLat([-96.41778916767144, 39.90201978025539]);

        const basemapTileLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
            title: 'BaseMaps',
            displayInLayerSwitcher: false,
            source: new ol.source.OSM({
                'url': "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            })
        });
        basemapTileLayer.set('name', 'tileLayer');
      
      const imageWMSSource = new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wms',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'topp:states'},
        ratio: 1});

        //Map Creation
        var map = new ol.Map({
            controls: controls,
            interactions: interactions,
            target: 'olCesMap',
            layers: [basemapTileLayer,new ol.layer.Image({
      extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
      source: imageWMSSource
    })],
            view: new ol.View({
                center: center,
                zoom: zoom
            })
        });
        //Cesium Viewer constructed based on Ol.Map
        var cesViewer = new olcs.OLCesium({
            map: map,
            sceneOptions: {
                mapProjection: new Cesium.WebMercatorProjection()
            }
        });
        //Cesium Viewer scene
        var scene = cesViewer.getCesiumScene();
        //Cesium Viewer enable
        cesViewer.setEnabled(false);

        //Cesium Viewer depthtest
        scene.globe.depthTestAgainstTerrain = true;
    </script>
    </body>
```

UPDATE: I tried with Ol-Cesium v2.10, but I got these errors:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level
> of a module olcesium.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: olcs is not defined

Comment: What version of ol-cesium are you using?

Comment: OL-Cesium: v2.9 Cesium: v1.70

Comment: That was released in April 2019, ol-cesium was not made fully compatible with OpenLayers 6 until October 2019, see https://github.com/openlayers/ol-cesium/pull/714 and https://github.com/openlayers/ol-cesium/issues/725

Comment: Thank yor your help, but it seems that the structure of the new OL-Cesium version 2.10 is different. I downloaded it but there are more JS files in its folder in addition to this, the size of the olcesium.js file is much smaller than the version 2.9. And I get these errors on the console: Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module olcesium.js:4    and   Uncaught ReferenceError: olcs is not defined   Why?   How to use the new version?

Comment: There is a full zip file download avaiable via https://openlayers.org/ol-cesium/

Comment: @Mike Thanks, but now I think that the problem is that I wrote my code is in an old format. I don't use "import" and my OL code syntax is not the same as the official OL6 examples, in addition to this I don't use npm, Nodejs etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old syntax can still be used with full builds https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/quickstart.html

The latest olcesium builds are also available via jsdelivr so no need to download.

I tried your code with that and the problem with ImageWMS seems unrelated to version, but it does work with TileWMS

```
<html>
<head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/css/ol.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.70/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.70/Build/CesiumUnminified/Cesium.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol-cesium@2.11.3/css/olcs.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol-cesium@2.11.3/dist/olcesium.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        html,
        body,
        #olCesMap {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #btnSwitchMap {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 50px;
            z-index: 2;
            padding: 4px;
        }
    </style>
</head>  
<body>
    <div id="olCesMap">
        <button id="btnSwitchMap" onclick="cesViewer.setEnabled(!cesViewer.getEnabled());">Switch 2D/3D</button>
    </div>
    <script defer>
        var controls = ol.control.defaults({
            rotate: true,
            rotateOptions: {
                tipLabel: "Reset rotation. \nUse Alt+Shift+Drag to rotate the map."
            }
        });
        var interactions = ol.interaction.defaults({ altShiftDragRotate: true, pinchRotate: true });

        // Declaring Zoom level to further view
        var zoom = 5;
        // Declaring Map center
        var center = ol.proj.fromLonLat([-96.41778916767144, 39.90201978025539]);

        const basemapTileLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
            title: 'BaseMaps',
            displayInLayerSwitcher: false,
            source: new ol.source.OSM({
                'url': "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            })
        });
        basemapTileLayer.set('name', 'tileLayer');
      
        const tileWMSSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wms',
            params: {'LAYERS': 'topp:states'},
            ratio: 1
        });

        //Map Creation
        var map = new ol.Map({
            controls: controls,
            interactions: interactions,
            target: 'olCesMap',
            layers: [basemapTileLayer, new ol.layer.Tile({
                extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
                source: tileWMSSource
            })],
            view: new ol.View({
                center: center,
                zoom: zoom
            })
        });
        //Cesium Viewer constructed based on Ol.Map
        var cesViewer = new olcs.OLCesium({
            map: map,
            sceneOptions: {
                mapProjection: new Cesium.WebMercatorProjection()
            }
        });
        //Cesium Viewer scene
        var scene = cesViewer.getCesiumScene();
        //Cesium Viewer enable
        cesViewer.setEnabled(false);

        //Cesium Viewer depthtest
        scene.globe.depthTestAgainstTerrain = true;
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE** ImageWMS does work with the latest olcesium and OpenLayers 6.5.0

```
<html>
<head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/css/ol.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.70/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.70/Build/CesiumUnminified/Cesium.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol-cesium@2.11.3/css/olcs.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol-cesium@2.11.3/dist/olcesium.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        html,
        body,
        #olCesMap {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #btnSwitchMap {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 50px;
            z-index: 2;
            padding: 4px;
        }
    </style>
</head>  
<body>
    <div id="olCesMap">
        <button id="btnSwitchMap" onclick="cesViewer.setEnabled(!cesViewer.getEnabled());">Switch 2D/3D</button>
    </div>
    <script defer>
        var controls = ol.control.defaults({
            rotate: true,
            rotateOptions: {
                tipLabel: "Reset rotation. \nUse Alt+Shift+Drag to rotate the map."
            }
        });
        var interactions = ol.interaction.defaults({ altShiftDragRotate: true, pinchRotate: true });

        // Declaring Zoom level to further view
        var zoom = 5;
        // Declaring Map center
        var center = ol.proj.fromLonLat([-96.41778916767144, 39.90201978025539]);

        const basemapTileLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
            title: 'BaseMaps',
            displayInLayerSwitcher: false,
            source: new ol.source.OSM({
                'url': "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            })
        });
        basemapTileLayer.set('name', 'tileLayer');
      
        const imageWMSSource = new ol.source.ImageWMS({
            url: 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wms',
            params: {'LAYERS': 'topp:states'},
            ratio: 1
        });

        //Map Creation
        var map = new ol.Map({
            controls: controls,
            interactions: interactions,
            target: 'olCesMap',
            layers: [basemapTileLayer, new ol.layer.Image({
                extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
                source: imageWMSSource
            })],
            view: new ol.View({
                center: center,
                zoom: zoom
            })
        });
        //Cesium Viewer constructed based on Ol.Map
        var cesViewer = new olcs.OLCesium({
            map: map,
            sceneOptions: {
                mapProjection: new Cesium.WebMercatorProjection()
            }
        });
        //Cesium Viewer scene
        var scene = cesViewer.getCesiumScene();
        //Cesium Viewer enable
        cesViewer.setEnabled(false);

        //Cesium Viewer depthtest
        scene.globe.depthTestAgainstTerrain = true;
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a perfect answer! It works. Thank you very much!